# Having issues with how to use ' or " in sql statement and query using concatrelated function

Tags: vba, ms-access, concatenation

I have the following code using the ConcatRelated function. the current sql works with 1 where condition but I can't figure out how to get the sql to work with 2 conditions. It works when use it in a query. I get issues and the code does not debug.

```
            ItemsShpdInvSQL = "SELECT InvoiceAllShippedItems.ShipmentID, InvoiceAllShippedItems.ShipType, " _
                            & "InvoiceAllShippedItems.BillTo, InvoiceAllShippedItems.CustID AS Consignee, " _
                            & "InvoiceAllShippedItems.PayMethod, InvoiceAllShippedItems.PaidInFull, " _
                            & "First(InvoiceAllShippedItems.Units) AS Units, " _
                            & "'Freight Charges - Ref. WR: ' & (ConcatRelated('[WR]'," _
                            & "'[InvoiceAllShippedItems]','[BillTo] =' & [BillTo])) & " _
                            & "' - (' & Sum([Chargeable]) & ' ' & [Units] & ' " _
                            & ") - Number of Pieces: ' & [NoPieces] AS InvDetails, " _
                            & "Sum(InvoiceAllShippedItems.[# of Pieces]) AS NoPieces, " _
                            & "Sum(InvoiceAllShippedItems.Chargeable) AS Charge, " _
                            & "CustRate([custid],[ShipType]) AS CustomerRate, " _
                            & "IIf(([Charge])<6.1,20/[Charge],[CustomerRate]) AS RateMin " _
                            & "FROM InvoiceAllShippedItems " _
                            & "GROUP BY InvoiceAllShippedItems.ShipmentID, " _
                            & "InvoiceAllShippedItems.ShipType, InvoiceAllShippedItems.BillTo, " _
                            & "InvoiceAllShippedItems.CustID, InvoiceAllShippedItems.PayMethod, " _
                            & "InvoiceAllShippedItems.PaidInFull, InvoiceAllShippedItems.Units, " _
                            & "CustRate([custid],[ShipType]) " _
                            & "ORDER BY InvoiceAllShippedItems.BillTo;"
                            '& "CustRate([custid],[ShipType]);"
```

with this it works in a query but not in the code above:

```
'concatrelated("[WR]","InvoiceAllShippedItems","[BillTo]&[PayMethod] ='" & [BillTo] & [PayMethod] & "'")
```

Comment: Your show { character instead of [ in: `{BillTo]`

Comment: Strongly advise not to use spaces nor punctuation/special characters in naming convention.

Comment: Is BillTo a number type field? Is this Allen Browne's ConcatRelated function? Probably better to build this query as an object then VBA pulls from that query object for a recordset.

Comment: Thank You @June7. I fixed the {BillTo]. I am not sure I understand your answer and yes I am using Allen Browne's ConcatRelated Function. Still Learning and I don't have the name of different actions down yet. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Build a query object with Access query builder. Then to open a recordset in VBA, reference that query object: `SELECT * FROM queryname`. Note that the closing semi-colon is not needed for the SQL when opening a recordset.

Comment: Or what else are you doing with this SQL statement?

Comment: I don't think the code will even run with the closing semi-colon in  ItemsShpdInvSQL

Comment: Thank you all. I found a solution at the Allen Browne site. I was not applying the ' correctly.

Comment: @mazoula, closing semi-colon should not be an issue, not needed, but not an issue.